# How to solve this error when getting html using node-horseman?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I use module `node-horseman` to run PhantomJS from Node. I would like to get html from github login page. This is my code.

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();
horseman
    .open('https://github.com/login')
    .html()
    .log()
    .close();
```

But I get the error.

```
Unhandled rejection eval@[native code]
evaluatePage

global code
evaluateJavaScript@[native code]
evaluate@phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:390:39
phantomjs://code/bridge.js:121:61
    at /Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:989:36
    at tryCatcher (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.fromNode.Promise.fromCallback (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:178:30)
    at Horseman.<anonymous> (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:987:29)
    at Horseman.tryCatcher (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:504:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:561:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:598:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/larry/Desktop/repos/getFollower/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:543:15)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:523:5)
```

I read the readme but I can't find where the error is. I guess there may be some other problems. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: have you found any solution?